# Is there a way to update a record in an Arraylist without deleting the existing record?

Tags: java, arraylist, record, updates

I have an arraylist , where records are stored as objects. I want to know if there is a way to **update a record in an array list without deleting the existing record?**

For example, my records have attributes like first name, last name, initials, id etc. Is there a way to update the first name in a record, instead of having to give all the other attributes values as well?

Currently what I have done is when the user gives an id, I find it whether the id matches any record in the array and if it does, I delete it off the array and make the user enter all the details from the beginning.

Comment: I don't think if it will work but you give a try.. 
you can use the array.get(index) to get the object and then use change the name of it and store it at the same index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arraylist stores the reference and does not copy/create new objects. If you change the stored object reference, it will be reflected in the arrayList as well. Here is a sample code to demonstrate that:

```
package arraylistExample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Class represeting entity to be stored in Arraylist 
 * 
 */
class Person {

private String name;
private int age;
private String address;

public Person(String name, int age, String address) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", address=" + address
            + "]";
}


}
```

.

```
/**
 * Public class to run the demo
 *
 */
public class ArraylistObjectModify {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Add an arraylist and add elements to it
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    personList.add(new Person("Juned",32,"Bangalore"));
    personList.add(new Person("Ahsan",31,"Delhi"));
    personList.add(new Person("Sniper",1,"Grave"));

    //Print list elements before change
    System.out.println("Arraylist pre objects modification");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    for(Person person:personList) {
        System.out.println(person);
    }

    for(Person person:personList) {
        if(person.getName().equals("Juned")) {
            person.setName("ChangedJuned");
            person.setAddress("Hola-lulu");
        }
    }

    //Print list elements after change
    System.out.println("Arraylist post objects modification");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    for(Person person:personList) {
        System.out.println(person);
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your record is an Object which contains mutable fields (getter and setter) like name ... Find the object by some identifier and simply call the setter with the new value to replace the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the set() Method.

Form Java API Docs:

```
set
public E set(int index,
             E element)
Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.
```

Taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update one or two values you can use setters. and if you know the index of your current object then you can add your new object to that index
eg:- Arraylist.add(index, element) this will update the existing element.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects should include a way to set/get their attributes, be this by directly accessing them, or through set/get methods.

For example

```
ArrayList<YourObject> Records = new ArrayList<YourObject>();

//Loop through your ArrayList and check if their ID attribute matches
for(YourObject record : Records) {
    if(record.id == userGivenID) {
        //prompt the user to change whichever values you want 
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Change the name of this record > ");
        record.setName(s.nextLine());
        ...etc...
    }
}
```

It is good practice to use get/set methods such as

```
record.setName("Bob");
String name = record.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check this example

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();

        Student s1 = new Student(1, "John", "Nash", "N");
        Student s2 = new Student(2, "John", "Slash", "s");

        al.add(s1);
        al.add(s2);


        for(Student s:al){
            if(s.getId() == 2){
                s.setfNmae("Nks");
                al.add(al.indexOf(s), s);
            }
           s.display();
        }

    }
}

class Student{
    private int id;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String initial;

    Student(int id, String fName, String lName, String initial){
        this.id = id;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.initial = initial;
    }
    void display(){
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(fName);
        System.out.println(lName);
        System.out.println(initial);
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fNmae
     */
    public String getfNmae() {
        return fName;
    }

    /**
     * @param fNmae the fNmae to set
     */
    public void setfNmae(String fNmae) {
        this.fName = fNmae;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lName
     */
    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lName the lName to set
     */
    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the initial
     */
    public String getInitial() {
        return initial;
    }

    /**
     * @param initial the initial to set
     */
    public void setInitial(String initial) {
        this.initial = initial;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i got it working using get/set methods. Thank you everybody.